# Git Merge Workflow

Tags: git, version-control, azure-devops, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Here is my solution for the merge workflow using VSTS and Git, diagram provided below.

This works but, seemingly, there are 2 redundant steps to prevent merge conflicts. I'm hoping that someone might have an easier way to do it in 1 step. If I rebase each branch, this will work but I'm trying to avoid that method. My steps include:

1. Make a dev branch, off master, and supplementary branches for features from dev.
2. Pull code into dev branch from feature branches.
3. Pull master into dev and resolve conflicts.
4. Pull dev into master once conflicts have been resolved.
5. Pull master back into dev so that commit history is the same.

[image: Git Workflow Image]

Comment: You don’t have to do step 5, since you’re just adding an empty merge commit.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it seems `master` is your main branch, `dev` is for you to have further development for your project, `feature` branches are work for mew feature or assist for you to develop on `dev` branch.
So the merge flow should be:

1. After `feature` branch’s work is finished, merge `feature` into `dev` (`git checkout dev` and `git merge feature`).
2. After finish work on `dev` branch, merge `dev` into `master` (`git checkout master` and `git merge dev`).

Now `master` branch contains the latest work from `dev` branch. And usually it’s not necessary to merge `master` back into `dev` since `master` is your main branch.

**Note:**

- When there have conflicts during merge, modify and save all conflict files, then use `git add .` and `git commit`. Or you can use merge strategy to solve conflicts automatically.
- Even though `git pull` from other branch may has the same result as `git merge`, I still suggest you use `git merge`. The command it exist for this situation and it’s more regular.